# Simple selects on Drizzle ORM doesn't work

Tags: typescript, next.js, orm

I wanted to try Drizzle for my latest project but I ran into an issue at the start. I use Next.js, Drizzle ORM and Neon (postgres).

I created a schema with `users` table like this:

```js
export const users = pgTable("users", {
    id: serial("id").primaryKey().notNull(),
    username: varchar("username").unique().notNull(),
});
```

This is my connection:

```js
import { neon } from '@neondatabase/serverless';
import { drizzle } from 'drizzle-orm/neon-http';

export const sql = neon(process.env.DRIZZLE_DATABASE_URL || "");
export const db = drizzle(sql, {logger: true})
```

But when I execute even a simple query like this:

```js
const data = await db.select().from(users);
```

I get empty array as a result, even though I know that there are rows.

Can anyone please help me how to fix this issue?

P. S. After further examination with logger enabled I found out that constructed queries are missing **semicolon at the end**. But this is only my speculation.

I get this:

```
Query: select "id", "username" from "users"
```

When I run it manually with `db.execute` I get the correct results only if I add the semicolon at the end.